# Dynamically change the background color of an object

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReports for generating the PDF form. The requirement is to dynamically set jrxml object backgroundcolor.

I tried to pass the color from java to jrxml. IT didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you changing the background of the entire report or just a report detail?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  Having a few text fields stacked with different colors and changing visibility is the solution we're currently seeking and I fear it'll be hard to keep track of things.... need a more robust solution.  What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to use styles of iReport and apply some predefied style 
   according to value of dynamically passed parameter.
2. Before generating the report you can parse jrxml using some lighter 
   language (Groovy, Ruby), find needed tag and correct value of appropriate 
   property.